# Finding transformation with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, transformation

Let $T:R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ be a non-invertible linear transformation that's represented with respect to the base: $ B = ((1,0,1),(0,1,-1),(1,-1,0))$

By the matrix:

$$[T]_B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & \alpha & 2\alpha \\ \alpha & 1 & 2\alpha \end{pmatrix}$$

I want to find $\alpha$ and the matrix that represent $T$ with respect to the standard basis.

I'm not sure how to begin with this exercise, can someone guide me please? 
I don't know what is the procedure of finding $\alpha$

Comment: To start: what are some ways you know of for checking if a matrix is invertible?

Comment: $det(M_B) = 0$ ? so does that mean that $\alpha = 1$?

Comment: That's correct. In terms of the second part of the problem, it would help if you already know the change-of-basis formula for matrices.

Comment: You mean $[T]_E = M_E^B[T]_BM_B^E$ where $E$ is the standard basis?

Comment: That's the one. You can easily find $M_E^B$ requiring that the vectors $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ each transform to the vectors in basis $B$ and solving for the matrix coefficients.